# Ad Hoc Javascript library returning undefined

Tags: javascript, data-structures, google-visualization

As said in the title, I'm trying to create a Javascript library from scratch which has to adjust the output of a chart created with Google Chart.

To explain better, Instead of doing this:

```
var options = {
      title: 'Top Consuming Nations - Thousand barrels daily',

      hAxis: {title: 'Year'},
      width: 1050, height : 400,

      vAxes: [
       {title: 'Top Countries', titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'},  maxValue: max},  // Left axis maxValue: 60000
       {title: 'Total World', titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'},  maxValue: tot}  // Right 
      ],
      series:{
        6: {targetAxisIndex: 1}
      },
      legend: { position: 'top', alignment: 'start' },
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(chartDiv));

    chart.draw(data, options);
```

I want to do something like this with a library created by me (skewedChart):

```
 var options = {
      title: 'Top Consuming Nations - Thousand barrels daily',

      hAxis: {title: 'Year'},
      width: 1050, height : 400,

      vAxes: [
       {title: 'Top Countries', titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'},  maxValue: max},  // Left axis maxValue: 60000
       {title: 'Total World', titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'},  maxValue: tot}  // Right 
      ],
      series:{
        6: {targetAxisIndex: 1}
      },
      legend: { position: 'top', alignment: 'start' },
      skew: 1
    };

var chart = skewedChart.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(chartDiv)); 

chart.draw(data, options);
```

This is the code of my library, contained in the file skewedChart.js:

```
    var skewedChart = {};
    skewedChart.visualization = {};

    skewedChart.visualization.LineChart = function(location) {
        this.chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(location) ;
        this.draw = function(data,option) {
            option.height = this.skewHeight(option.width, option.skew) ;
            option.vAxes[0].maxValue = this.skewMax(option.vAxes[0],option.skew) ;

            this.chart.draw(data,option);
        }
        this.skewHeight= function(width,skewFactor) {

        }
        this.skewMax= function(series, skewFactor) {

        }
    };
```

The problem is that the chart returns "undefined", why? How can I do it better?

Comment: you don't return anything...

Comment: @epascarello Even I  noticed  the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not return anything from a function call it returns undefined which is what you are seeing. You need to add `return this;` at the end of your function.